# Remove leading zeros in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there any way to remove leading zeros in pig?

eg: 000965326 -> 965326

number of digit can vary so cannot simply substring fixed number of digits.

Thanks in advance,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
000965326
00001010101
11111111111
010101
0000000000
```

**Pigscript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'0*(\\d+)?', 1);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(965326)
(1010101)
(11111111111)
(10101)
()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEX_EXTRACT instead of substring with regex like:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT('0001010', '([0]*)([1-9]*)', 1);
```

Comment: the above only keeps the zeros doesnt cut it